# How can I add objects to the screen when I press the mouse button?

Tags: java, awt

I am currently making a tile based game. Everything so far is working fine. However, I want the player to be able to add objects, like stone or wood to the screen when he/she presses the mouse button. I attempted this myself but it is not working. Here is what I have done, but is not working:

This is my KeyInput class, where all the keyboard and mouse events take place.

```
    public static ArrayList<StoneTile> sTile = new ArrayList<StoneTile>();

public KeyInput(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;

}


public void tick(LinkedList<Square> object) {}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();
    System.out.println("Pressed (X,Y): " + mx + " " + my);

    sTile.add(new StoneTile(1,mx,my));

    if(sTile.add(new StoneTile(1,mx,my))){
        System.out.println("ADDED");
    }
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("Released");
}
```

Here is my StoneTile class, this is what I want to add to screen:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.LinkedList;

    public class StoneTile extends Tile {

Textures tex;
public StoneTile(int id,int x,int y) {
    super(Textures.stoneArray[0], id);
    Tile.x = x;
    Tile.y = y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}


public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y,Tile.TILEWIDTH,Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
  }

}
```

The Textures.stoneArray[0] is simply the image that I want to add to the screen.
The Tile.(instance variable, like x, y, TILEWIDTH, and TILEHEIGHT) is simply a Tile class that contains all the render methods for the tiles (grass, stone, etc). If anything is unclear  I will clarify or if you need any code provided, then I will add it in.

Note - The ArrayList was just an idea that I had in mind, if there are more efficient ways of doing this or any better ideas, I am open to all of them.

Here is where I set the MouseListener. I set it in an init() method and then called in a run() method (last line):

```
private void init() {
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();

    level = loader.loadImage("level.png");

    world = new worldLoader("res/worlds/world1.txt");

    handler = new Handler();
    WIDTH = getWidth();
    HEIGHT = getHeight();

    cam = new Camera(handler, Game.WIDTH / 2, Game.HEIGHT / 2);
    setWIDTH(getWidth());
    setHEIGHT(getHeight());
    tex = new Textures();
    //backGround = loader.loadImage("/background.jpg");


    handler.addObject(new Coin(100, 100, handler, ObjectId.Coin));
    handler.addObject(new newStoneTile(20,20,ObjectId.newStoneTile));
    handler.addObject(new player_Square(100,100, handler, ObjectId.player_Square));
    //handler.addObject(new OneUp(300, 150, handler, ObjectId.OneUp));

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    this.addMouseListener(new KeyInput(handler));
}
```

jcomponent, is this what you meant?

```
public class Window {   

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6482107329548182911L;
static final int DimensionX = 600;
static final int DimensionY = 600;

public Window(int w, int h, String title, Game game) {
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();




}
```

}

Comment: Please could you add the code for where you set the `MouseListener` and how you update the relevant `JComponent` (e.g. the overridden `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. I assume you're using Swing.

Comment: I added the area where I set the MouseListener, but I was not too sure what you mean by "update the relevant JComponent"

Comment: @d.j.brown could you help

Comment: I assume somewhere you're painting all this by overriding `paintComponent`, if so, when the mouse is pressed (and you update the state), you need to call `repaint` to trigger a new paint cycle

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to try and answer this question is to give a small example.

Essentially what needs to happen is the following (assuming my understanding of the problem is correct):

1. User clicks on the `JComponent`/`JPanel` to determine where to place a `Tile`. This will cause a `MouseEvent` that needs to be listened for and handled.
2. The `JComponent`/`JPanel` needs a `MouseListener` implementation which will create a new `Tile` object and add it to the `List` of the `Tile` objects. Once this is complete the `JComponent`/`JPanel` needs to know to `repaint()`. You do not override `repaint()` but rather `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, which will be called by `repaint()` (eventually).
3. The `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method will iterate over the `List` of `Tile` objects, drawing them to the `JComponent`/`JPanel` using the `Graphics` context for the component.

To illustrate this I have simplified your problem. Note this isn't the best way to solve the problem since the Model (game logic) and the GUI should be separated, ideally using Model View Controller / Observer pattern.

First and most importantly is the `GamePanel` class, which extends `JPanel`. It's sole role in this example is to display the game graphically and handle mouse clicks. i.e. handling the list of tasks noted above.

**GamePanel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    private List<Tile> tiles; // Stores the Tile objects to be displayed

    /**
     * Sole constructor for GamePanel.
     *
     * @param width the width of the game panel
     * @param height the height of the game panel
     */
    public GamePanel(int width, int height) {
        tiles = new ArrayList<>();

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        // Implement mouse events for when the JPanel is 'clicked', only using the
        // mouse released operation in this case.
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // On mouse release, add a StoneTile (in this case) to the tiles List
                tiles.add(new StoneTile(e.getX(), e.getY()));

                // Repaint the JPanel, calling paint, paintComponent, etc.
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Draws the Tiles to the Game Panel.
     *
     * @param g the Graphics context in which to paint
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // Make sure you do this

        // For this example, using black as the color to draw
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Iterate over the tile list and draw them to the JPanel
        for (Tile tile : tiles) {
            Rectangle tileRect = tile.getBounds();
            g.fillRect(tileRect.x, tileRect.y, tileRect.width, tileRect.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Second is the `GameFrame`, which extends `JFrame`. This is just a basic `JFrame` which adds a `GamePanel` object. I've also included the `main` method which will ensure the GUI is initialized on the Event Dispatch Thread.

**GameFrame**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final String TITLE = "Tile Game"; // Game Frame Window Title

    private final JPanel gamePanel;

    /**
     * Sole constructor for GameFrame.
     *
     * @param width the width of the game in pixels
     * @param height the height of the game in pixels
     */
    public GameFrame(int width, int height) {
        gamePanel = new GamePanel(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Performs final configuration and shows the GameFrame.
     */
    public void createAndShow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(TITLE);
        add(gamePanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Entry point for the program.
     *
     * @param args not used
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame(640, 480);
                gameFrame.createAndShow();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Finally, the other classes used in the example for completeness, `Tile` and `StoneTile`. Personally I don't see much benefit from using `Rectangle` inside the model, but each to their own and I wanted to keep the example somewhat similar to your currently implementation.

**Tile**

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public abstract class Tile {

    private int x, y, width, height;

    public Tile(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

**StoneTile**

```
public class StoneTile extends Tile {

    public StoneTile(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

One final comment. I notice that your `sTile` `ArrayList` is static, this should probably not be the case as it belongs to the class rather than a particular instance of the class.

Comment: Ok, so it works to an extent, which I appreciate, so thank you! However, instead of drawing on block of 64 by 64, it draws a whole bunch of them which cover the screen, except for other entities like the player. I believe this is because I commented the super.paintComponent(g); (paintComponent method). I know it shouldn't be but it came up with an error "The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type Object" If this error comes up because I have not extended JPanel, then I have a problem because my current Game  class already extends Canvas.

Comment: I can't comment on the exact cause of the issue but `Canvas` is part of the AWT library and it can result in strange results mixing AWT and Swing components. I'd suggest changing your `Canvas` to a `JPanel`. If you insist on using `Canvas` then you should override the `paint` method and not `paintComponent`.

Comment: I got the program it work with JPanel thank you! Is it possible to make the block stay in its position and when I press the mouse key, another block is added. Like in minecraft when the player places a block and then another, the first block does not disappear, so you're able to build stuff. I want to essentially be able to 'draw' things when I place blocks

Comment: @CodeLife if you repaint the `List` of `Tile` objects then all the existing `Tile` objects should be drawn in the same position assuming that 1) you do not alter their position, 2) you maintain all the `Tile` to repaint in some form of Collection.  The basic example in the answer produces the behaviour you desire.

Comment: I take it you are very experienced in programming and do not wish to undermine that, but are you sure it produces the output that I need? As I made two classes called GamePanel and GameFrame and copy/paste (just to make sure I did not do anything wrong in my code), and when I ran it, I clicked the mouse button and a black block was drawn to the screen (as written in your example) and then I clicked the mouse button again in a different position and the block from before disappeared and appeared in the area I had just clicked. Look, I do not expect you to help me any further or even reply.

Comment: Thank you though!